# Does a data structure that models the encoding specificity principle in memory exist?

Tags: classification, biology, memory

I find myself wondering if there exists a data structure with the following properties:

- Stores information
- Conforms to the [encoding specificity principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encoding_specificity_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the basic requirement of storage, it seems you are looking for some explicitly defined data organization providing a query interface which allows specifying, alongside the fundamental query params, 
a context and is able to use both these information items (instead of the first one only) to boost the query.

If this interpretation of mine is correct, the context-aware query database comes to my mind, here are some examples:

- [Context-Aware Query Classification](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/context-aware-query-classification/)

> In this paper, we propose a logical model and an abstract query language as a foundation of context-aware database management systems. The model is a natural extension of the relational model in which contexts are first class citizens and can be described at different levels of granularity.

[Querying Context-Aware Databases](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-04957-6_7)